# i want to change the pdf look into html look in html2pdf

Tags: html2pdf

**I want to display HTML design page when converting the page in PDF format.**
**Is this possible to do? If yes, how?**

Currently my HTML page is getting distorted when converting into PDF format while using html2pdf. My header is not as per I designed it.
How to set the value of header as per css?

The script i am using is PHP.
Basically i want to know can i replace my css with the html2pdf css creation?If yes , how and what is the process/procedure?

Please Guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the query on my own.

I figured it out that PDF only recognises table and not div.
So when you write an html/ design it , write in table format not div. It does not recognise float.

Hence the above question i mark as resolved.

Thanks